# sun.nio.fs.AbstractUserDefinedFileAttributeView.setAttribute(Unknown Source) exception

Tags: java

I'm not getting how to add a custom metadata for all file types like txt,doc,docx,xls,xlsx,ppt,pptx,pdf etc 
i have tried for txt file using  File class setAttribute() method but i am getting error .

```
Path path = new File("C:\\Users\\a.txt").toPath();

        try{

         Files.setAttribute(path, "user:custom_attribute", "value1");
         }catch(IOException e){

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

i am not getting where i am going wrong ... i am getting this  below error

```
     java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.nio.ByteBuffer
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractUserDefinedFileAttributeView.setAttribute(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.setAttribute(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.setAttribute(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UserDefinedFileAttributeView to define your custom attributes :

```
final UserDefinedFileAttributeView view = Files.getFileAttributeView(path, UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
view.write("user.custom attribute", Charset.defaultCharset().encode("text/html"));
```

Comment: hi, the program is working but when i right click the file and checked in the property the custom attribute which have been added is not visible ,why?

Comment: Because it's a custom attribute. What do you want to use this attribute for? Maybe you could use an existing one instead of a custom one.

Comment: actually i will scan the file if it contains some keywords (like example:sensitive) i want to add a custom metadata for that file .

Comment: custom metadata like : classification_of_file    and              value like           :sensitive ,                                          where can i check for the added custom metadata in the file like we check for other metadata of a file by right clicking the file and checking in the property field.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are stored as sequences of bytes and therefore the `setAttribute` expects a sequence of bytes. If you want to store a `String` you have to convert it using a defined charset.

```
try
{
  ByteBuffer bb=StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode("value1");
  Files.setAttribute(path, "user:custom_attribute", bb);
} catch(IOException e)
{
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Getting the value back again requires a conversion from bytes to a `String`

```
try
{
  byte[] b=(byte[])Files.getAttribute(path, "user:custom_attribute");
  String value=StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(b)).toString();
  System.out.println(value);
} catch(IOException e)
{
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: hi, the program is working but when i right click the file and checked in the property the custom attribute which have been added is not visible ,why?

Comment: The property sheet of the Explorer never shows custom file system attributes. Don’t mix them up with file properties which Windows-specific handlers extract from the file’s content (like MP3-Tags or Word file properties).